# force users to capture video with low resolution with HTML5 video input capture

Tags: javascript, html

I have an option to capture video and upload it via my website.

I want to force the capture to low resolution (and only specific seconds).

I'm using the HTML5 video tag.

```
<input type="file" id="uploadVideoInput" name="uploads[]" class="file_multi_video" accept="video/*" />
```

is there a way to do it?

**Guys, I'm talking about uploading a video by selecting the input file or upload a recorded video from camera(mobile)**

Comment: How is video captured? What do you mean by "low resolution"?

Comment: When clicking on the input in mobile phone there is an option to capture a video from camera or upload a video file (from PC it's only upload), And I mean by lower resolution is to make the video smaller than it is.. Is know that mobile camera recording video with an high resolution (3K*2K), I want to force the video to be like 600*400

Comment: Not certain if that functionality is possible without processing the file after user selects file for upload.

Comment: let it record and then you compress the video in what format size you want. Dont force the user to do that, that sucks

Comment: @Nicholas I want to do it in order to help the user for waiting less till the upload finish

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of uploads for videos from mobile devices:

**"On the spot" video uploads**

This is where you click a file upload button and choose the option from your OS to record a video.

There's no standard way to tell the browser what type of video to record. [Some phones](https://addpipe.com/blog/video-quality-when-recording-videos-from-safari-on-ios-through-html-media-capture/) have settings to control the resolution/quality. But I've noticed on iOS (lately) that it forces you to record at the lowest resolution, regardless of your settings.

I agree w/the comments, for best user experience let the user upload whatever their phone sends, then transcode the video on the server/in the cloud.

**Uploading existing video files**

You could use things like the HTML5 File API to enforce limits on the file size and even the resolution. I won't add any code here, the file size is straight forward.

For resolution, what I did was to [load local video file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8885701/398606) into a `<video>` tag, and then add a "loadedmetadata" event listener to it. When the "loadedmetadtata" event fires, you can then get the `videoWdith` and `videoHeight` [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10514310/398606).

I did this on the desktop, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work on a modern phone :)

Comment: do you know of a way to bypass the iPhone "low resolution capture"? No matter what the settings they record 320p quality.

Comment: @StefanosChrs did you find a solution?

Comment: @damingzi It's an Apple policy and even with a ton of reports from the community they don't plan to change it. In the end I have to create a native mobile app to tweak the settings.