# How to get video box's currentHeight use jquery

Tags: jquery, html, video

[image]

As the images,the video box's height is ***367px***,but when I use the jquery to get the height, "`$('#bannerVideo').height()`" is console log ***619px***.So why is ***619px***.

I want to get the value ***367px*** not ***619px*** so how should I do?

Comment: Can you show us an example showing your error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the html5 video element's width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512529/how-can-i-get-the-html5-video-elements-width-and-height)

Comment: I add a images and I don't know can you see it.If you can,you will know my problem.