# How can I get the html5 video element's current height

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple html5 video tag:

```
<div id="videoBox">
  <video id="video" width="100%" controls loop>
    <source src="some_url"></scource>
  </video>
</div>
```

The problem is that how can I get the current height of the video?
I have tried by jquery:

```
$('#videoBox').height();
```

it return me the size 600px;
but I inspect the div on the page, I see the height is 372px;
So I want to get the value 372px,not 600px.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the html5 video element's width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512529/how-can-i-get-the-html5-video-elements-width-and-height)

Comment: Try that : $('#video').height(); and tell us what you get

Comment: I tried `$('#video').height();`, it's the same value of `$('#videoBox').height();`